# Why does sqlite insert only one column?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I get only the second value inserted into the database.  dataHold.Id has a value, as does aTextField.  However, when I look at the database, the Id isn't being inserted.  Is the sqlite below correct?

```
const char *sql = "insert into Userdata (Id, Name) Values(?, ?)";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
      sqlite3_bind_int(selectstmt, dataHold.Id, 1);
      sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 2, [aTextField.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_step(selectstmt);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should this

```
sqlite3_bind_int(selectstmt, dataHold.Id, 1);
```

be

```
sqlite3_bind_int(selectstmt, 1, dataHold.Id);
```

?